# special printing with awk

Tags: git, bash, awk

I want to print my git branches using awk, and I want only the branch name, without the origin and without knowing what is my working copy.
I came up with `git branch -r | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'` but the result looks like this:

```
origin/Dev
origin/HEAD
origin/master
```

So I tried `git branch -r | awk -F'/' '{print $2}'` and the result was:

```
Dev
HEAD -> origin
master
```

1. What is the way I can stay only with the branch name?
   (I don't care about a "git" solution, I want to know how to achieve that with awk)
2. How can I replace in the same line the line breaks with comma? For example my goal is to see it like this:

   ```
   Dev,HEAD,master
   ```

Thanks.

Comment: What about `git branch -r | awk '{n=split($1,a,"/"); print a[n]}'`?

Comment: @fedorqui the implicit assumption there is that the local branches have the same name as the remotes

Comment: Could you indicate what is the output of your `git branch -r` and what is your desired output based on it?

Comment: the output is: 
  origin/Dev
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
I want: Dev,HEAD,master

Comment: And if possible, eliminate HEAD (I bet somehow with the git command)

Comment: [edit] your question to include the output of `git branch -r` (without post-processing by your current attempts) so we can help you write a tool to parse that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print out the desired result, the comma separated string

```
git branch -r | awk '
    BEGIN { firstBranch = 1 }

    # split branch off from remote
    { branch = substr($1, index($1, "/") + 1) }

    # eliminate HEAD reference
    branch == "HEAD" { next }

    # output comma between branches
    !firstBranch { printf "," }
    firstBranch { firstBranch = 0 }

    # output branch name
    { printf branch }

    # final linebreak
    END { print "" }
'
```

or as one-liner without comments

```
git branch -r | awk 'BEGIN { firstBranch = 1 } { branch = substr($1, index($1, "/") + 1) } branch == "HEAD" { next } !firstBranch { printf "," } firstBranch { firstBranch = 0 } { printf branch } END { print "" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 ... | awk -F' +|/' -v ORS=, '{if($3!="HEAD") print $3}'
```

Comment: most elegant output.

Comment: This solution has two major drawbacks. **1.** It outputs an additional comma in the end of the string. **2.** It does not handle branches with slashes in their name correctly. If you have branch `original/foo/bar` and branch `original/foo/baz` it will output two times `foo` instead of the correct ones `foo/bar` and `foo/baz`. My solution does not have these flaws, though it is a bit longer of course.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it:

```
awk -v OFS="," '{ n = split($1, a, /\//); branches[++b] = a[n] } 
    END { for (i = 1; i <= b; ++i) printf "%s%s", branches[i], (i<b?OFS:ORS) }'
```

This gets the last part of each local branch (it assumes that your local branches don't have `/` in their names). It stores each name in an array and then prints them out, separated by a comma (using `OFS`) and followed by a newline (using `ORS`).

It would be easy to add a conditional `if (a[n] != "HEAD")` before adding the branch to the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch -r | awk -F/ '{sub(/[[:space:]]*->.*$/,"")}{print $NF}'
```

should do it.

**Output**

```
Dev
HEAD
master
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my example:

```
git branch|awk '{print ($1=="*" ? $2 : $1)}'|awk 'ORS=NR?",":"\n"'
```

`git branch` - prints branches,

`awk '{print ($1=="*" ? $2 : $1)}'` - prints name, not `*` before current branch,

`awk 'ORS=NR?",":"\n"'` - replace `\n` with `,`.

My result is:

```
ZIIPR-1247,ZIIPR-Config,develop,master,stage
```

Hope it is most simplest example...